# store values from loop in a list of lists or a list of tuples

Tags: list, loops, while-loop, tuples, output

there!

I try to output all the possible part-of-speech(pos) of each word in the text. However, I need to print the output as "a list of lists" or "a list of tuples" for the further use.

Anyone can help, many thanks!

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text = "I can answer those question ."     # original text
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)       # word tokenization
wsj = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_words()  
cfd1 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(wsj)       # find all possible pos of each word

i = 0
while i< len(tokenized_text):
    pos_only = list(cfd1[tokenized_text[i]])
    y = pos_only
    print(y)
    i+=1
```

**my output is**

```
['NNP', 'PRP']
['MD', 'NN']
['NN', 'VB']
['DT']
['NN', 'VBP', 'VB']
['.']
```

**my expected output is**

```
[['NNP', 'PRP'], ['MD', 'NN'], ['NN', 'VB'], ['DT'], ['NN', 'VBP', 'VB'], ['.']]
```

**or**

```
[('NNP', 'PRP'), ('MD', 'NN'), ('NN', 'VB'), ('DT'), ('NN', 'VBP', 'VB'), ('.')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to create an empty list and append elements during iteration. I assumed `print(y)` outputs `['NNP', 'PRP']` etc. Then you should convert `y` to a tuple and append it to the list during iteration. This piece of code should do it.

```
alist = []
i = 0
while i < len(tokenized_text):
    pos_only = list(cfd1[tokenized_text[i]])
    y = pos_only
    alist.append(tuple(y))
    i += 1
print(alist)
```